# How can I repair the damaged coating in my bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

The cat peed in our tub and I poured pure white vinegar in the tub to deodorize. I left about an inch of it in the tub for a couple of days. After I drained it I noticed that the glaze was gone where the vinegar touched the tub!

How do I repair this? I don’t want to install a new tub.

Comment: You could try getting a bathtub restoration kit but I don't think there is much you can do otherwise. Next time the car (cat I believe) pees in the tub just use regular water and dish soap. No reason to go to such extremes.

Comment: What is this tub made of? Fiberglass, cast iron? If it's fiberglass you can probably buff and wax it. If it's cast iron, probably not as easy.

Comment: @MicahMontoya, i agree with you about simply rinsing the tub .... even soap should not really be needed to remove the urine ..... i think that there may be more information that the OP has left out .... the leaving of the vinegar for a couple of days is very odd

Comment: We did that and the smell lingered. That’s why we used vinegar. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are DIY coating kits available and there are companies that will come and do it. I'd personally go with the professional job unless cost is a limiting factor. You'll likely get a tougher and better looking result.

Answer (score -1):

I highly doubt that plain household vinegar would damage a ceramic or enamel coating of a bathtub. So there are two other possibilities:

1. The tub was already refinished with a poorly chosen material, maybe even just painted, in which case getting a good quality tub refinishing kit is probably the best choice.
2. There was a thick film of old soap scum on the tub that you THOUGHT was the normal surface and the vinegar has actually removed THAT, taking it down to the REAL finish, in which case the approach would be to use vinegar on the REST of the tub and make it all look the same.

Comment: [Maybe](https://coloradotubrepair.com/when-not-to-go-all-natural-5-natural-cleaning-agents-that-can-damage-your-tub/). [Maybe not](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/how-to-clean-an-old-porcelain-enamel-bathtub-or-sink-137148).

Comment: I can feel the change in texture. There is a visible line where the level of the vinegar was. Also I can feel that there is no glaze in the area where the vinegar was.